# Rolling a d20 dice, dnd mecanics related

Tags: probability

lets say  i'm rolling a d20  dice  i need to get a 15 or higher and as a bonus i happen to roll 1 i get to re roll the dice and try again once.

what is the chance for success?

should i consider chance for success on the 1º  roll (lets call is S1) + chance for success on the 2º roll (lets call it S2) ? or am i doing it completely wrong?

to calculate S2 should i use P(A|B) assuming A and B are independent or how should i calculate it?

assuming i should use P(S) = P(S1)+P(S2) and P(S2) = P(A|B); A is getting 1 on 20 and B a success roll

P (S1) = 6/20 = 0,3

P(A|B) = $P(A \cap B) /$P(B)

assuming $A$ and $B$ are independent $P(A \cap B) = P(A).P(B)$

P(S2) = P(A|B) = P(A) = 1/20 = 0,05

P(S) = P(S1) + P(S2) = 0,3 + 0,05 = 0,35$$

is this right? what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Do you reroll when you have twice rolled a $1$?

Comment: Welcome to our site!

Comment: you re roll if you have 1 in the 1º roll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, $P(A\cap B) = P(A) \cdot P(B)$ (times, not divided) if $A$ and $B$ are independent.
Secondly, we should be cleaner about events and random variables. Let $X_1, X_2$ be the number thrown on the first / second throw. Then
$$\begin{align*}
P(S)& = P(X_1 \ge 15) + P(X_2 \ge 15 | X_1 = 1) \\
& = P(X_1 \ge 15) + P(X_2 \ge 15) \cdot P(X_1 = 1) \\
& = \frac6{20} + \frac6{20} \cdot \frac1{20} = \frac{126}{400} = \frac{63}{200} \\
& = 31.5\%
\end{align*}$$

Comment: ok, so the whole process i though was wrong. ty

Comment: You may find it easier to think of events as sets where some random variables (like $X_1$) satisfy a condition. If you have any further need for clarification, ask away. Else feel free to click the checkmark next to the answer once it becomes available.

Comment: i need to retake some lessons lol, probability its my worst mat subject